# How to create a signature, date page?

Tags: formatting

I need to create a signature page as shown in the image below in LaTeX. I have no clue on where to start and the commands that I would need. Could someone please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would create a macro that contains the construction of the name/signature/date setup. Then you can pass parameters to the macro so it can be somewhat dynamic.

In the minimal working example below, the macro `\namesigdate[<width>]{<name>}` does exactly that. You can pass it `<name>` which prints the name of the person at the top. This argument is mandatory. The width of the line is set at `5cm` (default). If you want to change this, you can use the optional `<width>` argument that takes any known (La)TeX length:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\namesigdate}[2][5cm]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{#1}@{}}
    #2 \\[2\normalbaselineskip] \hrule \\[0pt]
    {\small \textit{Signature}} \\[2\normalbaselineskip] \hrule \\[0pt]
    {\small \textit{Date}}
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\noindent \namesigdate{Name1} \hfill \namesigdate[3cm]{Name2}

​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I've also formatted the "Signature" and "Date" to be print using `\small\itshape`, although that can be modified.

Answer (score 11):

There are many way to do this. One way would be to use a `minipage` to generate each of the signature blocks.   This could be further enhanced to use `tikz` to draw the line which allows easier customization in terms of the line style that you want.

---

### Basic Solution:

Here is the basic `minipage` solution (adapted from Werner's):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\namesigdate}[2][5cm]{%
\begin{minipage}{#1}
    #2 \vspace{1.0cm}\hrule\smallskip
    \small \textit{Signature}
    \vspace{1.0cm}\hrule\smallskip
    \small \textit{Date}
\end{minipage}
}
\begin{document}
\noindent \namesigdate{Name1} \hfill \namesigdate[3cm]{Name2}
​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

---

### Enhanced Solution:

Here is the "overkill" version using `tikz`:

[image]

I have shown a few of the customizations that are available. See the TikZ/PGF manual for more options if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\namesigdatehrule}[1]{\par\tikz \draw [blue, densely dotted, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (#1,0);\par}
\newcommand{\namesigdate}[2][5cm]{%
\begin{minipage}{#1}%
    #2 \vspace{1.0cm}\namesigdatehrule{#1}\smallskip
    \small \noindent\textit{Signature}
    \vspace{1.0cm}\namesigdatehrule{#1}\smallskip
    \small \textit{Date}
\end{minipage}
}
\begin{document}
\noindent \namesigdate{Name1} \hfill \namesigdate[3cm]{Name2}
​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```