# Reduce spacing between lines

Tags: spacing

I have alternating lines and texts. Example may be a sign-in sheet where there is a line on which a person sign and his name is written immediately below this line. The following code generate the desired output except the last entry. There is relatively more space between the line and the name. Is there a way to reduce that space between the last line and Dr. EEEEE.

```
  \vspace{1.5cm}     
  \line(1,0){300}\\
  Dr. AAAAA\\
  \vspace{1.1cm}   
  \line(1,0){300}\\
  Dr. BBBBB\\
  \vspace{1.1cm}   
  \line(1,0){300}\\
  Dr. CCCCC  \\
  \vspace{1.1cm}
  \line(1,0){300}\\
  Dr. DDDD \\
  \vspace{1.1cm}   
  \line(1,0){300}\\
  Dr. EEEEE
```

Thanks

Comment: Related Questions: [dynamic signature/date line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/dynamic-signature-date-line/), [How to create a signature, date page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35942/how-to-create-a-signature-date-page/).

Comment: Please, add code that can be compiled; what I get from that snippet, with a standard preamble, is that the *first* entry is printed differently from the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\def\HS{\rule[-1cm]{0pt}{1.1cm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\Centering}b{300pt}}\hline
\HS  Dr. AAAAA\\\hline
\HS  Dr. BBBBB\\\hline
\HS  Dr. CCCCC\\\hline
\HS  Dr. DDDD \\\hline
     Dr. EEEEE
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A slight modification to your answer might be more in line with what your OP wants. See my deleted answer.

Comment: Thanks Herbert, but I needed the names to appear after  each line and aligned in the center. I am not able to do this as modifying the above code results in the 'noalign' error.

Comment: @learner: see edited answer

Comment: @Herbert, Thanks. Workes exactly as desired.

Answer (score 5):

You can adjust vertical spacing using `vspace` with negative argument as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46147/71097). Example:

`\vspace{-\baselineskip}`