# DOD-style signature page

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

Ok this is what I'm trying to build:

[image: Desired Result]

The closest answer I found online was this:
[How to create a signature, date page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35942/how-to-create-a-signature-date-page)

But I am failing banging it into shape; I have tried both Tikz and Minipage but honestly I haven't used LaTeX in many years (and I was never good at it before, either!)

Comment: You could easily do that with a  simple `tabularx` environment.

Comment: @Bernard I'll look at that right now thanks

Comment: If you have any difficulties, feel free to ask. Might it be more than one page long?